# How to punctuate multiple associated questions?

Tags: questions, punctuation, semicolons

I wrote this earlier, and it seems like the second sentence is a fragment.  Do you I need to combine the sentences?

> Just so we're clear, were all the files sent, now?  Including any files from 4/26 after 9:19 PM?

Comment: Are you asking if the second sentence is a fragment? Or are you asking if you need to combine them? Or are you asking for someone to rewrite the sentences into one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess I just want the correct handle multiple questions.  I guess is I had two sentences that are closely coupled I would using a semicolon.  However, for questions that does seem to work.  It seems like I get multiple closely related questions fairly often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To punctuate multiple associated questions in a sentence, you can use commas. In your example, you can revise the sentences as follows to make them grammatically correct:

> "Just so we're clear, were all the files sent now, including any files from 4/26 after 9:19 PM?"

This revised sentence uses a comma to separate the two related questions and makes it one complete sentence.

Comment: I .like this answer. Just putting a comma there makes sense.  Thank you.